# map JSON string to entity without nested entity

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3 and i need to map JSON string into entity. Json string contains only the key reference of nested entity:

I receive a JSON string like:

```
{"entities":
    [{
    "entityName":"User",
    "values":
    [
    {"name":"Mario","lastname":"Rossi","id_type":"1"},
    {"name":"Giuseppe","lastname":"Verdi","id_type":"1"}
    ]
    }]
}
```

and I have 2 java entities:

```
User{
   String name,
   String lastname,
   UserType userType
}
```

and

```
UserType {
   int id,
   String description
}
```

I want to create my User entity using JSON information.
User class have not "id_type" parameter so ObjectMapper cannot put JSON String in User entity.

I can recieve different kind of entity, so I use reflection in this way:

```
//READ JSON
GenericEntity entities[]=request.getEntities();
String entityName = entities[0].getEntityName();
Object rows[] = entities[0].getValues();
//MAP
Class clazz  = Class.forName(entityName);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
dbEntity = mapper.convertValue(rows[0], clazz);
//SAVE TO DB
service.save(dbEntity);
```

I think I have to use a CustomObjectMapper but I don't know how

I have also reverse problem:
I get "user" of User class and I have to create JSON String with "id_type"

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the only way to accomplish this would be to get the raw String JSON value from the request and manually convert.  Depending on which JSON library you are using (Jackson, FlexJSON) it should provide a means to custom-map the JSON values to the respective object values.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use DTO-object. e.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/v1/foos"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public void createFoo(@RequestBody FooDTO requestDTO) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

but converting is required anyway.